# Calculating cumulative multivariate normal distribution

Tags: stata, normal-distribution

I have 1000 observations and 3 variables in Stata that are associated with 1000 people. Let's say the data looks something like this (I just make up the numbers)

| Observation | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -3 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | -3 | 2 |
| 3 | 6 | -2 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 3 |
| ... | .. | ... | ... |
| 1000 | .. | .. | ... |

Which has a correlation matrix (again made up numbers)

R = (1, 0.5, 0.5 
0.5, 1, 0.5 
0.5, 0.5, 1 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

I want to calculate the CDF of the multivariate normal distribution of variables B1, B2 and B3 for each of the 1000 persons, using the same correlation matrix. Basically, it is similar to Example 3 in this document: https://www.stata.com/manuals/m-5mvnormal.pdf, but with 3 variables, and rather than multiple limits, multiple correlation matrix, I will do multiple limits and single correlation matrix. So basically, I will have 1000 CDF values for 1000 people. I have tried `mvnormal(U,R)`. Specifically, I wrote:

```
mkmat B1 B2 B3, matrix(U)
matrix define R = (1, 0.5, 0.5 \
 0.5, 1, 0.5 \
 0.5, 0.5, 1 \
 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) 
gen CDF = mvnormal(U,R)
```

But this doesn't work. Apparently this function is not on Stata anymore. I believe Stata has `binormal` for calculating the CDF of bivariate normal. But is it able to do the CDF of more than 2 variables?

Comment: The problem is that this is a Mata function and not a Stata function -- which is why it is documented as a Mata function. You can't call Mata functions as you did. You need to do this in Mata.

Comment: I still can't get it to work in mata. Do I write the command as I do in stata, or do I have to add something else in? It still says "command mvnormal not recognized" in mata.

Comment: Sorry, but your problem is too large to be solved in comments. Sometimes I see a question and it's a few minutes' work to write a few lines of code, This question is not like that for me, so you have to hope that someone else sees this and wants to answer. I would rate the chance of that as minimal. It would be nice for you if I was very wrong.